# install pycurl in another virtualenv

Tags: python, pycurl, python-venv

Here is my situation:

I work on a python project in which we work within a particular, project-oriented-and-customized virtual environment.

However at some point I need to introduce 3rd party modules into this venv, concretely speaking, pycurl and openpyxl. Presently I had to run certain python scripts depending on these two modules from anaconda's venv, which includes those two.

I don't feel like to switch back and forth between these two venvs.

We have a corp firewall stopping direct access to outside code repository. I managed, however, to download pycurl from https://dl.bintray.com/pycurl/pycurl/, after unzip it (BTW, I use Windows), I noticed these two packages

```
site-packages\curl
site-packages\pycurl-7.43.0-py3.5.egg-info
```

In my project's directory tree, I found bunches of modules pretty much in line with the naming conventions as above, they are all under:

```
my_project\PythonVenv\Lib\site-packages
```

Then I copied curl and pycurl-7.43.0-py3.5.egg-info there and re-activate the project's venv, and tried running the script, still it complains:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycurl'
```

Maybe simply copying doesn't work? Do I need to use something like "python setup.py" or "pip install".

First, I didn't see setup.py coming with the pycurl package; secondly "pip install" not work due to the corp firewall.

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you should be using the Windows binary packages. It sounds like you are trying to unpack the source distribution.